# How to create login management for custom entity in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login-register

I would like to create  a sales rep custom entity.

and I do not want to use customers (create an attribute called customer type is sales rep or not ) achieve the functionality.

How to create custom session login?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

This will be a very heavy module. A lot of things will be time taking to include here. But I will add some heads up.

Firstly you will need to have your custom storage. For this add the below code to your `di.xml`

```
<type name="NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Session">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">custom_session_storage</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

And your model class:

```
namespace NameSpace\YourModule\Model;

class Session extends \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager
{}
```

Now, you can build your own other logics along with blocks, templates, and controllers.

Basically, you will want to hold anything in your custom session.

For example:

In any class, add this:

```
private $customSession;

public function __construct(
    \NameSpace\YourModule\Model\Session $customSession
) {
    $this->customSession = $customSession;
}

//
public function setCustomData($data)
{
    $this->customSession->setData("custom_name", $data);
}

public function getCustomData()
{
    return $this->customSession->getData("custom_name");
}
```

Hope this helps.